# Adding elements to a Map in F# using a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, dictionary, f#, addition

Code:

```
let studentMap =
    for i = 0 to count do
        Map.empty.Add(students.[i].getId(), students.[i].getScores())
```

---

I am trying to add to a map sequentially. I have student objects in an array and am trying to add them in order. I am confused at how to do this. I thought maybe you make an empty map then add to it in order via a for loop, but it always causes trouble and won't work. Is there a way to add items to a map using a for loop? The `<key/value>` pairs are this: `<string, int array>`. That is the way I want it formatted but it keeps giving me trouble. I'll restate the goal again to clarify: I want to be able to add items to a map using a for loop with my student objects array being used to get the appropriate data I need in there. I will be able to give it a string and get back that student's grades for example. I know it's a weird problem I'm working on, but I needed to try something simple at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a mutable map variable:

```
let studentMap = 
    let mutable m <- Map.empty  
    for i = 0 to count do  
        m <- m.Add(students.[i].getId(), students.[i].getScores())
    m
```

or a mutable dictionary:

```
let studentMap = 
    let m = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Scores>()  
    for i = 0 to count do  
        m.Add(students.[i].getId(), students.[i].getScores())
    m
```

a more functional solution would be to use a fold:

```
let studentMap = seq { 0 .. count } |> Seq.fold (fun (m: Map<int, Scores>) i -> m.Add(students.[i].getId(), students.[i].getScores())) Map.empty
```

Comment: Yea I don't know why I didn't use mutable lol. Though on that second part I had to use let mutable m = Map.empty instead though.

Answer (score 10):

You can try a more functional idiomatic approach:

Let's say you have an array of type `Student` (in the example below is an empty array):

```
let students = Array.empty<Student>
```

You can transform your array in to a `Map`:

```
let mapStudents = students 
                    |> Array.map (fun s -> (s.getId(), s.getScore()))
                    |> Map.ofArray
```

Comment: Seemed like it still gave me issues, but I will research more on functional programming as whole anyways so I can start to understand this more. But I will save it and try to get it working.

Comment: What kind of issues do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Map.ofArray approach is probably the best, but it is worthwhile to point out that the for loops can done a bit better:

```
let map = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Scores>()
for student in students do
   map.Add(student.getId(), student.getScore())
```

This neatly avoids making array bounds mistakes.

Comment: This has the problem that `Map` is immutable.  You need to reassign the variable returned from `Add`

Comment: I have added the class of the map to clarify

Answer (score 2):

In functional languages, the built-in data structures are **immutable**, that is, when you add an element, a new value of the data structure is returned.

If you want to convert one structure to another, you can often use one of the build-in functions like `Map.ofArray`. If you have a more complex scenario, like a function generating your values, then you can use a **'loop'**, and each iteration of the loop returns a new value of the data structure. The way to express such a 'loop' in a functional way, is to use a **recursive function**:

```
let studentMap =
    let rec loop currentMap i =
        if i >= count then currentMap
        else
            let newMap = Map.add (students.[i].getId()) (students.[i].getScores()) currentMap
            loop newMap (i+1)
    loop Map.empty 0
```

Now you have full flexibility in how you generate the values (they don't have to be part of an array) and you're **avoiding mutable variables** that are un-idiomatic in functional programming. Ideally, like in this case, the function should be [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail%5fcall) to allow tail-call optimisation (and avoid stack overflow for large inputs).